# Window 7 - Dual monitors window alignment off

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, aero-snap

I have this problem where the taskbar takes up the whole screen on my main monitor, but when I try to drag a window and have it snap to the left side of my main monitor, it leaves a gap of about two inches.  It's really annoying since even when I maximize one window, I am losing the two inches in the viewing area.  Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to your question? I'm having a hard time visualizing what's going on here.

Comment: http://imgur.com/apclehO - This is a screenshot of the main monitor.

Comment: It almost looks like the Windows Sidebar is enabled -- can you check that? (I don't have a Windows 7 box handy, so can't provide steps on how to do so.) If I recall correctly, when enabled, the sidebar prevents maximized windows from overlaying it, with a result that resembles the above.

Comment: Glad to be of help! I'll convert it to an answer so you can formally accept it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Windows Sidebar is enabled. You can disable that by right-clicking the area where maximized windows don't show, and choosing "Close Sidebar".